# How to show realtime output SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making a form in a box. I have to give input, and whatever I enter will be shown in the box as I type. I have got to the point where I get input but I am unable to show on the box.

Here's the snippet:

```
case Event::TextEntered:
    if (isSelected)
    {
        char print;
        int xcor = 149;
        sf::Text t;
        t.setFont(font);
        do
        {
            print = event.text.unicode;
            //149.25

            t.setCharacterSize(15);
            t.setColor(Color::Black);
            t.setString(print);
            t.setPosition(xcor+1, 25);
            window.draw(t);
            //window.display();
        } while (event.text.unicode!=13);

        //cout << (char) event.text.unicode;    
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should draw the text every frame, whether there was a `TextEntered` event or not. You will also need a string to store the text in. So your main loop would look something like this:

```
sf::String text_string;
sf::Text text;
text.setCharacterSize(15);
text.setColor(Color::Black);
text.setPosition(150, 25);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    // Process events
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case Event::TextEntered:
                if (isSelected)
                {
                    text_string += sf::String(event.text.unicode);
                    text.setString(text_string);
                }
                break;

            // other events ...
        }

    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(text)
    window.display();
}
```

Comment: cannot render it. i have layers of forms and if i call the clear etc functions, there is flickering. I want to click in a box, then write input and show it in realtime. what is its alternative?